# counsel-rg how to repeat last search?

Tags: projectile, counsel

When repeat invoking counsel-ag, counsel-rg, counsel-projectile-rg etc, how can I quickly bring back the previous search term without retyping the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M-p` will do it. Works like most list commands.

Comment: ah it's previous-history-element etc (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-History.html). Wasn't bound for me for some reason. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't use ivy in meantime, you can call `ivy-resume` which will resume your search.